# SQL Server adjust each value in a column by another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have two tables, `TblVal` and `TblAdj`.

In `TblVal` I have a bunch of values that I need adjusted according to `TblAdj` for a given `TblVal.PersonID` and `TblVal.Date` and then returned in some `ViewAdjustedValues`. I must apply only those adjustments where `TblAdj.Date >= TblVal.Date`.

The trouble is that since all the adjustments are either a subtraction or a division, they need to be made in order. Here is the table structure:

`TblVal`: `PersonID, Date, Value`
`TblAdj`: `PersonID, Date, SubtractAmount, DivideAmount`

I want to return `ViewAdjustedValues`: `PersonID, Date, AdjValue`

Can I do this without iterating through `TblAdj` using a `WHILE` loop and an `IF` block to either subtract or divide as necessary? Is there some nested SELECT table magic I can perform that would be faster?

Comment: Why not convert divide into subtract? It is much easier to aggregate.

Comment: You can't convert a divide into a subtract without knowing the value it will be applied to. For example, if there is a divide by 2, no fixed subtraction will always have the same effect as dividing by 2, regardless of the number to be halved.

Comment: You say "since all the adjustments are either **bold** a **bold** subtraction **bold** or a **bold** division" what is the 'other' value, is it NULL? Can they both be NULL? Also, I suspect the TblAdj table has fewer rows than the TblVal table, is this true? Also do you just need to update the table, or do you need to print out the results as well. One last thing, do you want to delete the tuple from TblAdj after the update is complete?

Comment: Correct, the "other" value in `TblAdj` is null, and `TblAdj` has fewer rows than `TblVal`. I was actually compiling `TblAdj` from two tables, we'll call them `TblSub` and `TblDiv`, by doing a union and order by Date, since I needed to go through them in order. Thus, `TblAdj` is just temporary and can be modified however, but doesn't need to be. Please also see my response to Steve Kass' solution below though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it without a loop, but whether you want to or not is another question. A query that I think works is below (SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3de7/1)). The key ideas are as follows:

Each SubtractAmount has the ultimate effect of subtracting SubtractAmount divided by the product of all later DivideAmounts for the same PersonID. The Date associated with the PersonID isn't relevant to this adjustment (fortunately). The CTE AdjustedAdjustments contains these adjusted SubtractAmount values.

The initial Value for a PersonID gets divided by the product of all DivideAmount values on or after that persons Date.

EXP(SUM(LOG(x))) works as an aggregate product if all values of x are positive. You should constrain your DivideAmount values to assure this, or adjust the code accordingly.

If there are no DivideAmounts, the associated product is NULL and changed to 1. Similarly, NULL sums of adjusted SubtractAmount values are changed to zero. A left join is used to preserve an values that are not subject to any adjustments.

SQL Server 2012 supports an OVER clause for aggregates, which was helpful here to aggregate "all later DivideAmounts."

```
WITH AdjustedAdjustments AS (

select
  PersonID,
  Date,
  SubtractAmount/
  EXP(
    SUM(LOG(COALESCE(DivideAmount,1)))
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY PersonID
        ORDER BY Date
        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
      )
  ) AS AdjustedSubtract,
  DivideAmount
  FROM TblAdj
)

  SELECT
    p.PersonID,
    p.Value/COALESCE(EXP(SUM(LOG(COALESCE(DivideAmount,1)))),1)
      -COALESCE(SUM(a.AdjustedSubtract),0) AS AmountAdjusted
  FROM TblVal AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AdjustedAdjustments AS a
  ON a.PersonID = p.PersonID
  AND a.Date >= p.Date
  GROUP BY p.PersonID, p.Value, p.Date;
```

Comment: By the way, I realized that you might have to make multiple adjustments for the same PersonID (i.e., if PersonID is not the primary key of TblVal), so I added an additional item to the outermost GROUP BY to group by p.Date as well. This query (with that adjustment) assumes that (TblVal.PersonID, TblVal.Date, TblVal.Value) is unique.

Comment: Hey, this works great, thanks a lot! Also, you were correct that the entire row represents a unique entry for `TblVal`, not just the `PersonID`.

Unfortunately we're still running SQL Server 2005. After reanalyzing the issue with a co-worker, we're thinking of calculating the adjusted values outside of the database, then storing them in an extra `AdjustedValue` column, and having another table that stores the `PersonID` with an `AdjustedDate` column that we can check against the most recent date for that `PersonID` in our `AdjTable` to see if we need to recalculate our `AdjustedValue`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following:

```
with CTE_TblVal (PersonID,Date,Value)
as 
(
   select A.PersonID, A.Date, A.Value 
   from TblVal A
   inner join TblAdj B
   on A.PersonID = B.PersonID
   where B.Date >= A.Date
)
update CTE_TblVal
set Date = TblAdj.Date,
    Value = TblAdj.Value
from CTE_TblVal
   inner join TblAdj 
   on CTE_Tblval.PersonID = TblAdj.PersonID
output inserted.* into ViewAdjustedValues
select * from ViewAdjustedValues
```